# Show that, if $A$ is Hermitian then $A^{-1}$, if it exists, is also Hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that $$A^{-1} = (A^{-1})^\dagger$$
I know that for a square matrix
$$A^\dagger=A$$
$$A_{ij}^\dagger=A_{ji}^*$$
$$(AB)^\dagger=B^\dagger A^\dagger$$

> My Prove:$$AA^{-1}=A^\dagger A^{-1}=1$$ Multiplied with $$(A^{-1})^\dagger$$ gives $$(A^{-1})^\dagger A^\dagger A^{-1}=(A^{-1})^\dagger A A^{-1}$$ $$(AA^{-1})^\dagger A^{-1}=(A^{-1})^\dagger 1$$ $$(1)^\dagger A^{-1}=(A^{-1})^\dagger 1$$ $$A^{-1}=(A^{-1})^\dagger$$
>   q.e.d.

Correct?

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to prove and what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry, first post. Trying to prove the statement above,which I translated in the first equation. The prove itself is in the quote.

Comment: @meffyx it would be good to clarify what the dagger notation means, and what $A$ is (i.e. is it a matrix over the reals, over any field, any ring, etc)

Comment: $\dagger$ here refers to the conjugate transpose. This is a fairly common alternative to just the $*$.

Comment: Had the tag "quantum mechanics", because its a common notation there. Question is an exercise from the book of Szabo and Ostlund. Dagger means take the complex conjugate of the transpose.But I dont know if this answers your question. Matrix elements may be complex.

Comment: @Meffyx it seems that this proof amounts to using the fact that, in general,
$$
(M^\dagger)^{-1} = (M^{-1})^{\dagger}
$$
This is usually the kind of thing given/proven in the text, so I would skim through to see if/where this is mentioned.

Comment: I use the following equations from the text. $$A=A^\dagger$$ $$(AB)^\dagger=B^\dagger A^\dagger$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems correct. You can also see it by using the properties of the scalar product:
$$
\langle A^{-1}u|v\rangle=\langle A^{-1}AA^{-1}u|v\rangle=\langle A^{-1}u\mid A(A^{-1})^\dagger v\rangle
$$
comparing the first and last expression, and since $A^{-1}$ is onto and $u,v$ were arbitrary, this means that $A(A^{-1})^\dagger=I$. Note that this is basically the same proof, only written in a different way.

Comment: aren't we supposed to prove the linearity as well?

Comment: @Ruvik: linearity of what?

Comment: of the inverse operator

Comment: @Ruvik: the inverse of a linear operator (if it exists) is always linear.